# C# Use delegate to replace if else code

Tags: c#, delegates

I know this method is working well. However I reused most of the code and it looks ugly... It should be possible to remove the ***if else*** using ***delegate***. Any thoughts?

```
public IHttpActionResult TimeDatawithUserandServer(string name, string group)
{
            List<Model> res = new List<Model>();

            //group 1 is Server type
            if (group.Equals("1"))
            {
                var realName = name.Replace("-", ".");
                IQueryable<Overalldata> UserData = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.Server.Equals(realName));
                var groupedUserData = UserData.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.User}).ToList();
                res.AddRange(groupedUserData.Select(item => new Model()
                {
                    Count = item.Count(),
                    Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    Name = item.Key.User
                }));
            }

            //group 2 is User type
            else
            {
                IQueryable<Overalldata> Serverdata = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.User.Equals(name));
                var groupServerData = Serverdata.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.Server}).ToList();
                res.AddRange(groupServerData.Select(item => new Model()
                {
                    Count = item.Count(),
                    Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    Name = item.Key.Server
                }));
            }
            return Ok(res);
}
```

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @displayName sure look forward to that.

Answer (score 1):

### Without Delegates

Your code can simply be refactored to following and relieved from repetition:

```
public IHttpActionResult TimeDatawithUserandServer(string name, string group)
{
    List<Model> res = new List<Model>();
    var groupedData = group.Equals("1") ? FetchServerData(name) : FetchUserData(name);
    res.AddRange(groupedData.Select(item => new Model()
        {
            Count = item.Count(),
            Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            Name = item.Key.Server
        }));
    return Ok(res);
}

private GroupedDataType FetchServerData(string name)
{
     var realName = name.Replace("-", ".");
     var UserData = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.Server.Equals(realName));
     return UserData.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.User}).ToList();
}

private GroupedDataType FetchUserData(string name)
{
    var Serverdata = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.User.Equals(name));
    return Serverdata.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.Server}).ToList();
}
```

Please replace the `GroupedDataType` with the appropriate type in the two methods above and in the code below.

---

### With Delegates

Using Reflection we find the correct field (or property) and then compare the value as in the code below:

```
public IHttpActionResult TimeDatawithUserandServer(string name, string group)
{
    List<Model> res = new List<Model>();
    var groupedData = GetGroupedList(group, name);
    res.AddRange(groupedData.Select(item => new Model()
        {
            Count = item.Count(),
            Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            Name = item.Key.Server
        }));
    return Ok(res);
}

private static IEnumerable<GroupedDataType> GetGroupedList(string group, string name)
{
    var filteredList = db.Overalldatas.Where(dbData => Filter(dbData, group, name));
    return filteredList.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.User}).ToList();
}

private static readonly Func<ODType, string, string, bool> Filter = (ode, group, name) =>
        {
            var objType = overallDataElement.GetType();
            var field = objType.GetMember(group)[0];
            return (field != null)
                && ((FieldInfo) field).GetValue(ode).ToString().Equals(name);
        };
```

`ODType` is Type of the elements in of Overalldatas list and `ode` is overalldata list's one single element.

Comment: Pretty neat... Thanks! One thing is that I don't want to mix API methods with private methods. All the methods in this class are responsible for handling Http requests... Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. I understand what you're doing here. I'm not talking about if the methods are private or public. I just don't want to mess my API controller with polymorphism - they should be located somewhere else.

Comment: hmm... this method is one of the methods in a controller class which inherits from ApiController class in ASP.NET. Its main responsibility is for return httpactionresult to serve the front end data. Your method will work obviously and it's pretty clean. I'm just thinking maybe there are some other ways that not using methods  -- like using delegate to dynamically check the parameter passed in. See the answer below which I like better.

Comment: @catlovespurple: Ohk... get it. Yes. Actually I think neither mine nor the other answer is good enough then. I'll give you what I am thinking (but unable to write in code) - The `FetchUserData` and `FetchServerData` should be instead just one function which takes in two inputs (string name and source). The `source` input should tell whether to match with Server or User in `x.{Server/User}.Equals(name)`.

Comment: Yes, you got what I meant. The thing you mentioned is exactly what I want. Whenever you have time, I believe a code snippet will be helpful as I just want to see how you plant to handle the output of **source**

Comment: @catlovespurple: Ok... if no one gives the answer before I find it, I will update my answer and name-tag you.

Comment: great! Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Thanks! Finally get some time in front of computer. The second one using reflection is exactly what I want! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
public IHttpActionResult TimeDatawithUserandServer(string name, string group)
{
    var getName = group == "1"
        ? (Func<Overalldata, string>)(od => od.Server)
        : (Func<Overalldata, string>)(od => od.User);

    var realName = group == "1"
        ? name.Replace("-", ".")
        : name;

    var UserData = group == "1"
        ? db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.Server == realName)
        : db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.User == realName);

    var groupedData =
        UserData
            .ToArray()
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.EventDate, Name = getName(x) })
            .ToArray();

    var res =
        groupedData
            .Select(item => new Model()
            {
                Count = item.Count(),
                Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                Name = item.Key.Name
            })
            .ToList();

    return Ok(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with a comment made by lc who suggested running this through a code review.

There are some potential anti-patterns in your code

- The group parameter is an example of [control coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))
- The control coupling is utilized via the if statement. For me, this is a clear sign that the method should be broken into separate methods.
- I would also like to call attention to the Overalldatas collection. It's name is suspicious which leads to other questions including "Is this data object trying to do too much?". But I won't really touch and this as it's less relevant to your question and my answer.

That said, my answer is that you should have two methods, one for "Server Type" and one for "User Type". I realize this pushes that "group" check elsewhere, but that can be solved later and today the intent of your methods will be MUCH clearer.

```
public IHttpActionResult TimeDataByUserName(string userName)
{
  List<Model> res = new List<Model>();
  IQueryable<Overalldata> Serverdata = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.User.Equals(userName));
  var groupServerData = Serverdata.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.Server}).ToList();
  res.AddRange(groupServerData.Select(item => new Model()
  {
    Count = item.Count(),
    Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
    Name = item.Key.Server
  }));

  return Ok(res);
}

public IHttpActionResult TimeDataByServerName(string serverName)
{
  List<Model> res = new List<Model>();
  IQueryable<Overalldata> UserData = db.Overalldatas.Where(x => x.Server.Equals(serverName));
  var groupedUserData = UserData.GroupBy(x => new {x.EventDate, x.User}).ToList();
  res.AddRange(groupedUserData.Select(item => new Model()
  {
    Count = item.Count(),
    Date = item.Key.EventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
    Name = item.Key.User
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Atoms! I guess your answer is mainly to avoid the group check. Even though the original function is broken into two parts, I still feel like there are too much common things in these two methods. Don't you think they're pretty similar? Any thoughts on a further abstraction?

Comment: The are similar, no doubt. But the crux is that you share one data object but extract completely different values from it. That's why I mentioned my eye-brow being raised around the Overalldatas collection. I would spend some time thinking about that before I spent any time making the code parts more reusable. I should also mention that sometimes reuse, for clever's sake, does more harm than good. Imagine taking some of the other answers provided and updating them to support even more variants vs. the pattern I've suggested here. Which would be easier to support?

Comment: I have to say Overalldatas is a bad name. It contains only 5 properties to interact with entity framework, nothing else. Yes, if I'm a new comer trying to understand code base, your methods are easier/cleaner to understand. I'm just gathering more thoughts and find the most appropriate way. Thanks for the inputs!